# sensor_msgs/Image

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is my first time dealing with sensor_msgs/Image. I am  using ros melodic in ubuntu 18.04. I tried to subscribe the content of sensor_msgs/Image and tried to visualize the data from the msg for validating the image. it cunfused me when I print the width, height , and the size of the matrice  data in sensor_msgs/Image. Why is the size value of matrice data in that msg different with height x width value ?  Could anyone explain me about this ?  (As I know the data is in the type of std::vector so I want to arrange it by dividing the data to an array[height][width] so I can validate and  visualize those  datas  in Matlab)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380511/sensor_msgs/image/) by [jenanaputra](https://answers.ros.org/users/58305/jenanaputra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not an expert to that so maybe I'm wrong. When looking at the documentation

http://docs.ros.org/en/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html

It actually mentions that

```
uint32 step           # Full row length in bytes
uint8[] data          # actual matrix data, size is (step * rows)
```

the size is step * rows no height x width. The reason for that is probably the fact that for each pixel you might not just have 1 byte but 3 bytes (e.g RBG).

---

Originally posted by [Webadone](https://answers.ros.org/users/72129/webadone/) with karma: 89 on 2021-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3